# How to become a good Python coder?

Tags: python

I started with c++ but as we all know, c++ is a monster. I still have to take it and I do like C++ (it takes programming a step further)

However, currently I have been working with python for a while. I see how you guys can turn some long algorithm into simple one.

I know programming is a progress, and can take up to years of experience.
I also know myself - I am not a natural programmer, and software engineering is not my first choice anyway. However, I would like to do heavy programming on my own, and create projects.

How can I become a better python programmer?

Comment: This is better to be asked as community wiki.

Comment: If only the hat had given you slitherin

Comment: @zincorp I want to downvote your comment so badly.  :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

- Write code
- Read books, http://www.coderholic.com/free-python-programming-books/
- Read code
- Read tutorials, [http://www.dabeaz.com/talks.html](http://www.dabeaz.com/), ...
- Write more code
- Do exercises, e.g. [Building Skills in Python](http://homepage.mac.com/s_lott/books/python.html)
- Write even more code
- Answer SO python questions, https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/python
- Check (your) code regularly, http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pylint
- Watch talks and presentations:

  - [Easy AI in python](http://us.pycon.org/2009/conference/schedule/event/71/),
  - [Advanced python or understanding Python](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E_kZDvwofHY),
  - http://pycon.blip.tv/, ...

Comment: the exercise link is broken, most people would downvote because its easier to click the down arrow oppose to take some time to write the comment

Comment: @aforloney: I believe that most SO users are conscious enough to prefer to write a comment before downvoting.

Comment: lol thanks guys. i never downvote anyone (and I don't see any point except for spammers) These are great resources, I will check them out once finals are over!!!

Comment: Make sure you mark this answer as correct if you're satisfied.

Comment: +1 Read code, gotta trump up the read code bit more. Especially since python's stl is available to read through.  Oh and Woa!  Slott wrote a book!

Answer (score 4):

Read code.  This will help you learn what works well in Python and what doesn't.  As part of this, learn python idioms and the standard library.

Some examples of literature to read:

- http://ivory.idyll.org/articles/advanced-swc/
- http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html
- http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/

As for the algorithm part you mention, some specific parts of the standard library to learn include:

- itertools
- functools
- contextlib

Comment: great. once finals are over i will check them out

Answer (score 4):

One suggestion is to find an open-source project in Python, and start contributing. You may ask "how can I contribute, if I'm a beginner?". One answer is "write tests". Almost any project will welcome you as a tester. Another answer is "documentation", though that is less likely to give immediate benefits.

Comment: I haven't thought about that! Thanks.

Comment: any recommendation for any open source project written in python? Thanks

Comment: see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/117561/what-are-good-open-source-projects-in-python-for-which-i-can-be-a-contributor

Comment: @MichaelEaster That link is dead as of now.

Comment: I think this is a great idea!

Answer (score 3):

The already-posted answers are great.

In addition, whenever you're coding something in Python and you start doing something that feels clumsy, take a step back and think. If you can't think of a more elegant way to do it, post it as a question on Stack Overflow. I can't count the number of times that I've seen someone reduce ten lines of Python into one (which is still perfectly easy to read and understand).

Comment: rofl but in real world application (let's jump all the way to Google), is it better to reduce 10 lines into one (if there is no change in performance)?

Comment: Absolutely, as long as that 1 line is still easy to read. Concise and understandable code goes an extremely long way towards an easy-to-maintain system.

Comment: Don't do anything like that on StackOverflow, it might get closed. Try [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 3):

in addition to suggestions pointed by "The MYYN" I would suggest use of [pylint](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pylint)

Comment: wooo i can use this tool after finals and start looking at my old codes :) thanks brother

Comment: maybe you should purchase an up vote! :-) brother